# angularjs restangular not getting data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am trying to get restangular working.  In my API (with the end point /user) I get this json response:

```
{
"error": false,
"response": {
    "totalcount": 2,
    "records": [{
        "id": "1",
        "groupId": "14",
        "fullName": "Mark Smith ",
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "groupId": "14",
        "fullName": "Joe Andrews",
    }]
}
```

}

I am using this in my service:

```
$scope.projects = Restangular.all('user').getList();
console.log($scope.projects);
```

This is the html:

```
 <li ng-repeat="project in projects>  
     {{project.groupId}} {{project.fullName}} 
</li>
```

I am not getting any data.

How can I access the data in the `response:{totalcount:2, records: [{...}]` and the data in the `records:[{...}]`?

My kung-fu is not enough to make it work.

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: but **project in projects.records track by $index** no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have your actual response wrapped. In that case you'll want to look at this part of the documentation: [Restangular Wrapped Response](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#my-response-is-actually-wrapped-with-some-metadata-how-do-i-get-the-data-in-that-case). You'll need to use the `addResponseInterceptor` to make sure it returns the right data.

Comment: Sanity saver! I was about to lose it with this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`getList` returns a promise. That's why you should use it with like this:

```
Restangular.all('user').getList().then(function(data) {
    $scope.projects = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (to setting your `$scope` variable inside of `then()`) you could do this:

```
$scope.projects = Restangular.all('user').getList().$object;
```

Which returns a promise and unwraps it for you.